# How to increase Score on google pagespeed insight tool of our gwt web application

Tags: java, gwt, google-pagespeed

On analyzing my website on google pagespeed insight tool I have just got the score of 57/100 for desktop with 7 rules passed.

[image: SnapShot of the pageinsight]

but when I tested for other blank project on pageinsight I got 96/100 with 8 rules passed.

[image]

I am still unaware how the rules are being passed and how the increase in score is related to the rules passed.

If you analyze stackoverflow it will only have 3 rules passed and 87/100 score.

***My question*** 
1) Now what else is left so as to increase my gwt web application score on pageinsight tool so to get an optimized website with perfect speed.

2) How are the no of rules related to the score?

Why we with higher no.of rules passed still have lower rank.

Comment: I wrote this long back. See might be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18488665/1927832

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already have gotten the answer. But you partly answered it your self - it seems that not every rule is equal and the numbers of "violations" also seems to count.

And compression seems to be one of the easy wins. Where elimination of the blockers is hard and sometimes nearly impossible when you are on CMS's that isn't build for optimized content delivery - but for extensibility and features for the editor.

I have seen sites with 4/4 and build a 100/100 test site myself, only to go down to 99/99 after putting Google Analytics on the page - since that script only have a 2 hours maximum age in the HTTP headers.